# Baystack 5510 Ethernet Routing Switch routing question

Tags: configuration, routing, nortel

I'm trying to create a static route on a Baystack 5510 Ethernet Routing Switch with the following:

```
ip route 192.168.104.220 255.255.255.255 192.168.100.253 en
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find entry to modify.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried adding the route without enabling it in the initial command?  I've seen that error before but it was a fairly old code revision where we had that happen.

Comment: I have tried that - it then says "% Incomplete command."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim - I just got the same error with the latest code.  Did you ever get it working?

I will answer my own question:

Despite what the syntax says with "?" use:

ip route x.x.x.x y.y.y.y d.d.d.d 1

The '1' is for a the cost.  Just like a router but you have to entre it, not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Could you verify that no route exists with

```
show ip route 192.168.104.220 -s 255.255.255.255
or
show ip route static
```

Also if you haven't configured any routing on the switch so far you can manually enable IP routing globally before trying to add the route with the following:

```
ip routing
ip route 192.168.104.220 255.255.255.255 192.168.100.253
```

You don't specify if you're trying to route a specific vlan or not, but you will have to have an assigned IP on the VLAN(s) you wish to have routing on.

Comment: I've added routes on this before, but I can't remember what I did differently.  I do not have this particular route configured however, it's a new entry.  I have 3 VLANs and all 3 are configured with IP's